# Sql Server - Count occurrences of datetime group by specific interval

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I have this table with sample data:

```
MY_TABLE
------------------------------------------
ID    DateVal                other columns
------------------------------------------
1     2017-01-14 11:00:00    ...
2     2017-01-14 11:01:00    ...
3     2017-01-14 11:02:00    ...
4     2017-01-14 11:03:00    ...
5     2017-01-14 11:11:00    ... 
6     2017-01-14 11:11:30    ...
7     2017-01-14 11:15:00    ... 
8     2017-01-14 11:15:01    ...
9     2017-01-14 11:18:00    ...
```

I need to have this kind of result:

```
start               end                 occurrences
-----------------------------------------------------------
2017-01-14 11:00    2017-01-14 11:05    4
2017-01-14 11:05    2017-01-14 11:10    0
2017-01-14 11:10    2017-01-14 11:15    3
2017-01-14 11:15    2017-01-14 11:20    2
...
```

In specific I need a query that extracts all the occurrences of raws in MY_TABLE in 5 mins range (range value is variable).

Someone could help me?

Best regards,

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: You need to use a tally table here to generate the time ranges.

Comment: Careful what you assume - 11:00 to 11:05 might consist of 6 individual minutes. Know your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's have a row generator, that generates dates every rangeSize from a startDate:

```
DECLARE @rangeSize INT = 5;
DECLARE @startDate DATETIME = '2020-01-01 00:00';

WITH RG(D,D2) AS (
   SELECT @startDate AS D, DATEADD(MINUTE, @rangeSize, @startDate) AS D2
   UNION ALL
   SELECT DATEADD(MINUTE, @rangeSize, D), DATEADD(MINUTE, @rangeSize, D2)
   FROM   RG a
   WHERE  D < DATEADD(MINUTE, @rangeSize * 100, @startDate)
)

SELECT D,D2
FROM   RG
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 100);
```

Now let's hook it up to your data and count the data:

```
DECLARE @rangeSize INT = 5;
DECLARE @startDate DATETIME = '2020-01-01 00:00';

WITH RG(D,D2) AS (
   SELECT @startDate AS D, DATEADD(MINUTE, @rangeSize, @startDate) AS D2
   UNION ALL
   SELECT DATEADD(MINUTE, @rangeSize, D), DATEADD(MINUTE, @rangeSize, D2)
   FROM   RG a
   WHERE  D < DATEADD(MINUTE, @rangeSize * 100, @startDate)
)

SELECT r.D as StartDate, r.D2 as EndDate, COUNT(m.ID) as Count as EndDate
FROM   
  RG r
  LEFT JOIN
  my_table m ON m.dateval > r.D AND m.dateval <= r.D2
GROUP BY r.D, r.D2

OPTION (MAXRECURSION 100);
```

Note I used `>` and `<=` for the range because you seem to classify from e.g 15:01 to 20:00 as a range, whereas it feels more natural to me to have 15:00 to 19:59 as "belonging to the 15-20 range"

Answer (score 1):

You need to generate the timeframes you want and then `left join`.  Here is one method:

```
select v.dt, dateadd(minute, 5, v.dt) as end_dt, count(t.id)
from (values (convert(datetime, '2017-01-14 11:00')),
             (convert(datetime, '2017-01-14 11:05')),
             . . .
     ) v(dt) left join
     my_table t
     on t.dateval >= v.dt and
        t.dateval < dateadd(minute, 5, v.dt)
group by v.dt;
```

Note:  If you want to do this for a wider range of time, then using a tally table or recursive CTE is handy.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need your start and end to reflect the exact range: 
You can use something like `DATEDIFF(minute, '2000-01-01', DateVal)/5` as your grouping, then use `MIN(DateVal)` and `MAX(DateVal)` for your `start` and `end`; but those values will be of the first and last transaction in the interval, not the bounds of the interval.

Alternatively, you can use a recursive CTE to generate the intervals, and then join that to your data:

```
; WITH intervals AS (
   SELECT CAST('2017-11-01 00:00:00' AS DATETIME) AS `start`
       , CAST ('2017-11-01 00:05:00' AS DATETIME) AS `end`
   UNION ALL
   SELECT DATEADD(minute, 5, `start`) AS, DATEADD(minute, 5, `end`) AS end
   FROM intervals
   WHERE intervals.end < '2017-11-02 00:00:00'
)
SELECT i.`start`, i.`end`, COUNT(t.ID) AS occurrences
FROM intervals AS i
INNER JOIN MY_TABLE AS t ON t.DateVal >= i.`start` AND t.DateVal < i.End
GROUP BY i.`start`, i.`end`
ORDER BY i.`start`, i.`end`
;
```

Notes:

- the literal date values can be adjusted to reflect the actual range you want to query
- If you want intervals without activity to be included, the INNER can be changed to LEFT
- Since your question as stated has overlapping intervals, I went with the assumption that a DateVal on the 5 minute mark belongs to the interval that starts with that value.